# Office.initialize in typescript

Tags: typescript, office-js

I have an Office AddIn where I want to put the Office.initialize method to ensure Office is initialized before I start using Office APIs. So I have put the following code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppView } from './View/AppView';

(function () {

    Office.initialize = () => {
        console.log("Office initialized");
        renderApp();
    }

    const renderApp = () => {

        ReactDOM.render(
            <AppView/>,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );
    }
})();
```

I am giving Office CDN URL in my corresponding cshtml file. But in this file I get the error 'TS2304: Cannot find name 'Office'.'

If I generate a sample add IN project using Yo Office, there I have no error, but here I am getting this error consistently. Can someone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Have you done “npm install —save-dev @types/office-js”?  That should get you the right package.
Note that you don’t need to import anything in your code for this to work, as Office declares its variables at the global level.

Comment: Yes looks like this was the issue. I added this package and now it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The message **error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Office'** can be solved with a *main.ts* file like this:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/office-js/index.d.ts" />
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const timer = {};

function startInterval(timer) {
  timer.id = setInterval(() => {
    if (Office !== undefined) {
      Office.initialize = (reason) => {
        platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(error => console.error(error));
      };
      stopInterval(timer.id);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stopInterval(id) {
  clearInterval(id);
}

startInterval(timer);
```

It will work for whom are creating new *Office Add-in* using *Angular*, instead *generator-office* package (*yo office*).

I hope helped you (all)!